# How to change Android colors.xml to change based on user preference

Tags: android, xml

Upon login, I'll be returned a User object on success and within the object, I'm able to tell the type of user. I want each user to share the same layouts but different theme colors. Is there a way to declare multiple groups of colors inside my colors.xml file? Or does it have to be done by creating a whole different colors.xml file?

I have something like this:

For Admin:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#E53935</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#B71C1C</color>
    <color name="accent">#212121</color>
    <color name="background_color">#F5F5F5</color>
    <color name="text_color_primary">#FAFAFA</color>
    <color name="drawer_fragment_background">#424242</color>
</resources>
```

For Normal User:

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#EEEEE</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#BBBBB</color>
    <color name="accent">#200001</color>
    <color name="background_color">#C5BEA3</color>
    <color name="text_color_primary">#FAFAFA</color>
    <color name="drawer_fragment_background">#424242</color>
</resources>
```

Based on the User object, I want the `@color/primary` to point to the specific set of colors. Is this done by sharedPreference files?

Comment: yes you can have 2 xml  just name them different like admin_colors.xml and colors.xml

Comment: @war_Hero If I do that, wouldn't I have to change the `attribute` for each layout file?

Comment: @war_Hero read question carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution i guess you have to define different colors as a_primary="#000" b_primary="#111" in colors.xml and then you can create different styles in styles.xml

```
<style name="a_Theme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/a_primary</item>
</style>

<style name="b_Theme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/b_primary</item>
</style>
```

and then apply theme according intent params onCreate as setTheme(android.R.style.a_Theme);

Comment: This didn't work when changing the background of my custom toolbar...I did a work around and created a class that handled the changing of themes and custom toolbar colors. Aside from that, this would work fine.